# Using Polycom API for my APP

Tags: iphone, ios, flash

I have read the PolyCom API and noticed that PolyCom is web-base (from what I have understood correctly).

I am developing an iphone App and would like to use this service. The problem that I am having is how to include it in my app. Is this worth it to call their app through my app and pass the number for the call to be made or to include their service in my app.

My app is being developed using flash as my app will for iphones and ipads.

Thanks

Comment: -snmp. This question does not seem to be SNMP related.

Comment: there wasn't any category for my problem